# Centering Embedded Content

Tags: html, css, embed, styling

I am relatively new to web development and my school has asked me to create a webpage that will host the school's webshow and I am having trouble centering the embedded video.

I tried adding an inline style `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the embed code but that is not centering it. I can change the margins manually but I want the video to be automatically centered whenever somebody visits the page.

Are auto margins not supported in embed tags?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SDL.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="background-image:url(img/Stage-Background.png)"; margin-top:100px; margin-bottom: 100px;>

<embed
src="http://blip.tv/play/AwGUv2w"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="669"
height="500" allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></embed>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Working simpler example showing margin style being ignored, at least on Chrome:

```css
/* does not center it: */
embed { margin: 0 auto; }

div, embed { border: 1px solid black; }
div { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div>
  <embed src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/se-logo.png">
</div>
```

On Windows Chrome that renders as:

[image]

Comment: You need to show us some HTML.
Try specifying a width to your video element + display block + margin: auto.

Comment: Give us sample of Your code.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the q seems clear (or was edited; didn't check timeline) and I actually have the same question (auto margin not being applied to `embed` tags).

Comment: I've also added a snippet example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your embed code, try to use the following just before and just after the embed code.

```
<center>
   <embed>
        //youtube url here..
   </embed>
</center>
```

or you could use this **margin: 0 auto;**

Comment: this works, but isn't the <center> tag a little outdated? is it still fully supported?

Comment: As far as I know its still supported(unless someone will disproved this). You could also use class to achieve this just wrap your <embed></embed> with divs and in the css you could use margin:0 auto; to center it.

Comment: <center> is now deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Could be, that's why I also suggested alternative solution if it were the case. No need for downvote.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated; and auto margin seems to be ignored on `embed` (OP also had this issue). At least, Chrome ignores it.